# org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property greaterThan found for type

Tags: mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

Does MongoRepository has $and operator? I was getting error when i try with and operator like below. I have checked the [document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html) and haven't noticed "and" keyword.

```
public interface AssetRepository extends MongoRepository<Asset, String>{

    @Query("select a from Asset a where ownerId = ? and timeUpdated > ?")
    public List<Asset> findByOwnerIdAndGreaterThan(final String ownerId, Date timeUpdated);
}
```

### Error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'assetRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property greaterThan found for type Asset!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property greaterThan found for type Asset!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.PartTreeMongoQuery.<init>(PartTreeMongoQuery.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory$MongoQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:128)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:369)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:192)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:225)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from your exception your query lookup strategy is `CREATE`, or you don't import `@Query` from the correct namespace (package).

You should change the method name to `findByOwnerIdAndTimeUpdatedGreaterThan`, assuming the `Asset` class has a `timeUpdated` property.

Or, resolving back to default lookup strategy, the following should work (I think):

`@Query("{ 'ownerId' : ?0 , 'timeUpdated' : {$gt : ?1}}")`

Notice that you currently use a JPA syntax in `@Query`, and not MongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

The code doesn't work for two reasons:

1. You're using JPQL with MongoDB which is not supported. If you want to manually define the query, use a MongoDB query (i.e. JSON).
2. The exception indicates the query is derived from the method name. `findByOwnerIdAndGreaterThan` doesn't make too much sense, as you need to define a property you want to apply `GreaterThan` to. So it probably needs to be something along the lines of `findByOwnerIdAndTimeUpdatedGreaterThan` judging from what you have listed as JPQL document.